# Uncaught ReferenceErrors Ytplayer and gtag

Tags: javascript

This website https://www.nycrugs.com is showing some errors I think are affecting the display of the store filter.[javascript error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmeJJ.png)
https://c2n.me/3UNed5Z.png
If you give me some guidance I can do it but I have no knowledge of JS.
I though to just delete those lines but am not sure were the code ends.
I didn't make the site that is why am facing theses strange errors.
gtag is giving errors too.
Anyway Sorry for my lack of knowledge please help.

Comment: you are using Youtube player API , and you need to wrap the call to  YT inside a function

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003216/javascript-youtube-api-variable-yt-is-not-defined this might help you out

Comment: `I though to just delete those lines` - yes, do that - no charge

Answer (score 0):

It error at https://www.nycrugs.com/wp-content/uploads/fvm/out/footer-ba7339dc-1528811528.min.js

Try go to this link to unminify a javascript file http://unminify.com/

At I found it error about  **"YTPlayer is not defined"** at line:13157
I'm not sure about this error but you may try to add "var" in front of YTPlayer = {

like this **var YTPlayer = {**

```
  YTPlayer = {
        player: null,
        defaults: {
            ratio: 16 / 9,
            videoId: 'LSmgKRx5pBo',
            mute: !0,
            repeat: !0,
            width: $(window).width(),
            playButtonClass: 'YTPlayer-play',
            pauseButtonClass: 'YTPlayer-pause',
            muteButtonClass: 'YTPlayer-mute',
            volumeUpClass: 'YTPlayer-volume-up',
            volumeDownClass: 'YTPlayer-volume-down',
            start: 0,
            pauseOnScroll: !1,
            fitToBackground: !0,
            playerVars: {
                iv_load_policy: 3,
                modestbranding: 1,
                autoplay: 1,
                controls: 0,
                showinfo: 0,
                wmode: 'opaque',
                branding: 0,
                autohide: 0
            },
            events: null
```

Comment: I deleted those lines until events: null. but still appear on the website. Remember I don't want any ytplayer I found this website already made at work and now those 3 errors are hurting the sales. https://c2n.me/3UNed5Z.png I never had to deal with this before. Why is the website not loading the new JS file?